# How do I 'translate' a Java enum-type to JRuby code?

Tags: java, enums, jruby, porting

How would I go about to translate this Java code to i.e. JRuby:

```
enum Note {

    REST, A4, A4$, B4, C4, C4$, D4, D4$, E4, F4, F4$, G4, G4$, A5;
    public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16 * 1024; // ~16KHz
    public static final int SECONDS = 2;
    private byte[] sin = new byte[SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE];

    Note() {
        int n = this.ordinal();
        if (n > 0) {
            double exp = ((double) n - 1) / 12d;
            double f = 440d * Math.pow(2d, exp);
            for (int i = 0; i < sin.length; i++) {
                double period = (double)SAMPLE_RATE / f;
                double angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * i / period;
                sin[i] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127f);
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] data() {
        return sin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding some context to your question would be useful. Do you need pass Notes to Java code that expects them to behave like the current Java object? Are you just trying to get similar functionality ported to Ruby, but not necessarily keep the exact same API? Do you just want to reference the existing Java class from Ruby clients?

Comment: If you respond to the comment after your question on enum types in Ruby, then someone might be able to provide you some sort of answer.